# JUnit publish test results is not working in Azure DevOps

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, junit4

Recently I've added a couple of unit / integration tests to my Spring Boot project. I want to check the results of those tests under the "Test Plan" section in Azure DevOps. I've heard that I can add a task to my pipeline that can publish test results. So I've add the following task to my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master
jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build Maven project and Docker build'
  steps:
    - task: replacetokens@3
      displayName: 'Replace tokens'
      inputs:
        targetFiles: |
          **/application-prod.properties
    - task: Maven@3
      displayName: 'Build Maven project'
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        goals: 'package'
        jdkVersionOption: 11
        publishJUnitResults: true
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-RESULT.xml'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Build Docker image'
      inputs:
        repository: 'myuser/cdb'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        tags: $(Build.BuildId)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Push Docker image to Docker hub'
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'Dockerhub connection'
        repository: 'myuser/cdb'
        command: 'push'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        tags: $(Build.BuildId)
- deployment: VMDeploy
  dependsOn: Build
  displayName: 'Deployment to VPS'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-20.04'
  environment:
   name: CDB_VPS
   resourceName: vps-a7b448br
   resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: docker pull myuser/cdb:$(Build.BuildId)
        - script: docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
        - script: docker run -d -p 8085:8085 myuser/cdb:$(Build.BuildId)
```

Will this task automatically generate a XML file if it does not exists? I've tried adding the file by myself but even then I get one of the following errors in my Build.

```
##[warning]No test result files matching **/TEST-RESULT.xml were found.
```

or when I add the XML file manually:

```
##[warning]Failed to read /home/vsts/work/1/s/TEST-RESULT.xml. Error : Root element is missing..
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Maven task executes each default lifecycle phase in order (**`validate`**, **`compile`**, **`test`**, etc.) before executing the goals you specified (**`package`**). More details, you can reference to "[**Maven build lifecycle**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#)".

In your case, please try with the following ways:

1. Change the pattern of test results files as '**`**/TEST-*.xml`**'.
2. Change the Search folder as '**`$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`**'.

Comment: I've added these two ways, still getting a warning that test result files can not be found. I am using a Ubuntu virtual machine. Can this be the problem? For my information: do I need to manually create an empty xml file or does JUnit make this?

Comment: Hi @GijsdeWert,
Normally, the test result report files should be generated automatically. The OS of the agent machine generally does not affect it.
You can try directly run the Maven CLI (e.g. `mvn test`, `mvn package`, etc.) for your project on the machine to see if it can work as expected. If the problem still exists, I think the problem may be caused by the configurations or settings on your project itself.
In addition, you also can report an issue on the "[microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues)" repository to ask more help.